# Listening on tap device for packets written through file descriptor

Tags: linux, networking, tap

I have a problem fully understanding how to use tap devices.

I've created a tap device and brought it up and running.
A user space programs opens its file descriptor and receives the Ethernet frames sent to the device. The tap device gets the IP address and netmask 10.254.0.1/24.
That works great up to this point. I do a `echo "test" | netcat -uq0 10.254.0.2 12345`, the program receives the packet and forwards it to another machine via another communication method.

But the other way around does not work at all:
The userspace program writes a valid Ethernet frame to the file descriptor of the tap device. But a `netcat -ul 12345` does not receive anything. Same with `socat`. I also tried to create a bridge and add the tap device to it, that did not work either.

I'm confused because if I monitor the tap device with Wireshark I can see each packet and each packet is correct.
The counter `tx packets: XY` of the command `ifconfig` is increased by each frame the userspace program writes to the tap device.
ARP is disabled by `ip link set dev tap0 arp off` because for now only IP packets shall be processed.

You can visualize my setup as following:

```
         host1              (some channel)               host2
netcat --> tap0 --> prog   --------------->    prog  -->  tap0  -->  netcat
<=============== works ========================================>| does not work
```

Do you have an idea how I can receive a packet "on the other end" of the tap device? Or where I can further read?

**EDIT2**:
Removed edit. (Wrong conclusion from wrong test. There was a problem with a checksum. Now the packets are valid, but are not received either.)

Answer (score 3):

Some further investigations through `netstat -s` helped me find the cause:
The Reverse Path Filter dropped my packets. (Up to now I did not fully understand why...)

Setting the filter on the tap device to a loose mode made it work:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tap0.rp_filter=2
```

(Disabling it by setting this to `0` did **not** work for me.)